# jquery video player support all formats in slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using slider in my site with video player (jwplayer). But this player not supporting  AVI format.
I have google it, many jquery player not supporting AVI format with slider concept.

Is there any reference for this one?

Thanks.

Comment: So the real issue here is that AVI isn't supported by JWPlayer and you want an alternative, right? I don't see how the slider has anything to do with that.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Yes i want alternative way for this.

Comment: Please consider converting your AVI files to a newer, web safe, standardized format. At this time, there is extremely little support for it, and it doesn't make sense to create code to support these.